# Disable automatic line break in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, linebreaks

In LibreOffice Writer, in a table cell, there is the text "abcdef/+ghijklm". The cell is not wide enough to contain the whole text, so there is an automatic line break after the "/" even though "abcdef/+ghi" would fit into the line. How can I prevent the automatic line break?

I know how to insert a protected hyphen or a protected space, but how can I disable the automic line break in general? I didn't find any formatting option and no solution on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the behavior to break on punctuation cannot be disabled.  My recommendation, which you seem to already be aware of, is to add [U+2060](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm) after the slash to keep it from breaking.

Or, the unicode character [U+0338](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0338/index.htm) is a slash that will not break lines.  Note that this is a combining diacritic, which means that it attaches to the letter "f" to make a single character, rather than two.

Another method is to go to Format -> Paragraph -> Text Flow, and check Hyphenation - Automatically.  This seems to do the trick except that it adds a hyphen.  There is more about hyphenation [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Hyphenation_1).

The only other way is simply to add a manual line break after the "i".

A discussion is here: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5160

Comment: The text must not be changed in any way because it's an encrypted password. I only want to change the way the text is displayed. But if there's no formatting option, I'll accept it. Thx.